# помогите надо что бы кнопки были около видео а не внизу

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.js">
  <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/tt-norms-pro" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>gevabramyan</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--обо мне-->
  <center>
  <h1 class="about">обо мне</h1>

  <p class="about-text">
    <b>
      Привет, меня зовут Геворк Абрамян. Я Родился в 1990 году в городе Ташир республика Армения. В возрасте 14 лет семья переехала в Сибирь, в город Новокузнецк! В своих выступлениях я рассказываю об Армении, традициях, и курьезных ситуациях которые происходили со мной, а также делюсь впечатлениями о жизни в России и в Сибири в частности. Выступаю на ТНТ (stand up), на Youtube канале наш сайт, roast battle labelcom
    </b>
  </p>
<!--видео со мной-->
  <h1 class="video-so-mnoy">видео со мной</h1>


    <!-- Основной блок слайдера -->
    <div class="slider">

      <!-- Первый слайд -->
      <div class="item">
          <iframe width="1440" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CvHb-5bxLGw" title="оф не знаю I денис гвоздев" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
      </div>
    
      <!-- Второй слайд -->
      <div class="item">
          <iframe width="1440" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bSf1eAv3R8U" title="оф не знаю I вадим постильный" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
      </div>
    
      <!-- Третий слайд -->
      <div class="item">
          <iframe width="1440" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e1HgTbZ8s5w" title="ДУЭЛИ ХА-ХА 3 РАЗА х АБРАМЯН х ТАРЖУМАНЯН" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
      </div>
    
      <!-- Кнопки-стрелочки -->
      <a class="previous" onclick="previousSlide()">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="nextSlide()">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  
    <style>
      /* Слайдер: */
  .slider{
      max-width: 90%;
      width: 1440px;
      /* Положение элемента устанавливается относительно его исходной позиции: */
      position: relative;
      /* Центрируем по горизонтали: */
      margin: auto;
      height: 850px;
  }
  
  /* Картинка масштабируется по отношению к родительскому элементу: */
  .slider .item img {
      /* Элемент меняет размер так, чтобы заполнить блок и сохранить пропорции: */
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
  }
  
  /* Кнопки назад и вперёд: */
  .slider .previous, .slider .next {
      /* Добавляет курсору иконку, когда тот оказывается над кнопкой: */
      cursor: pointer;
      /* Положение элемента задаётся относительно границ браузера: */
      
      top: 35%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -22px;
      padding: 16px;
      /* Оформление самих кнопок: */
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 100px;
      left: 500px;
      /* Плавное появление фона при наведении курсора: */
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      /* Скругление границ: */
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  }
  .slider .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  
  /* При наведении курсора на кнопки добавляем фон кнопок: */
  .slider .previous:hover,
  .slider .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
  /* Анимация слайдов: */
  .slider .item {
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  @keyframes fade {
      /* Устанавливаем и изменяем степень прозрачности: */
      from {
          opacity: 0.4
      }
      to {
          opacity: 1
      }
  }
    </style>
  
    <script>
      /* Устанавливаем стартовый индекс слайда по умолчанию: */
  let slideIndex = 1;
  /* Вызываем функцию, которая реализована ниже: */
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  
  /* Увеличиваем индекс на 1 — показываем следующий слайд: */
  function nextSlide() {
      showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
  }
  
  /* Уменьшаем индекс на 1 — показываем предыдущий слайд: */
  function previousSlide() {
      showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
  }
  
  /* Устанавливаем текущий слайд: */
  function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }
  
  /* Функция перелистывания: */
  function showSlides(n) {
      /* Обращаемся к элементам с названием класса "item", то есть к картинкам: */
      let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  
      /* Проверяем количество слайдов: */
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      if (n < 1) {
          slideIndex = slides.length
      }
  
      /* Проходим по каждому слайду в цикле for: */
      for (let slide of slides) {
          slide.style.display = "none";
      }
      /* Делаем элемент блочным: */
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  }
    </script>
  


<!--контакты-->
  <h1 class="contacts">контакты</h1>

    <p class="number"><b>(менеджер) Ильясова Роза </b>

    <a href="+7(962)518-54-57" class="num"><b>+7(962)518-54-57</a></b></p>

    <p class="mail"><b>gevorkabramyn1990@mail.ru</b></p>
  </center>
  <br>

  <center>
    
    <div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;"><a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/org/dizayn_zavod/1732662883/?utm_medium=mapframe&utm_source=maps" style="color:#eee;font-size:12px;position:absolute;top:0px;">Дизайн завод</a><a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/category/entertainment_center/184106372/?utm_medium=mapframe&utm_source=maps" style="color:#eee;font-size:12px;position:absolute;top:14px;">Развлекательный центр в Москве</a><a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/category/rental_of_venues_for_cultural_events/15215599314/?utm_medium=mapframe&utm_source=maps" style="color:#eee;font-size:12px;position:absolute;top:28px;">Аренда площадок для культурно-массовых мероприятий в Москве</a><iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?ll=37.585289%2C55.805073&mode=search&oid=1732662883&ol=biz&z=14.31" width="1400" height="600" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="true" style="position:relative;"></iframe></div> 
  
  </center>

  <div class="ss">
    <a href="https://vk.com/gevabramyan" class="vk"><img class="vkimg" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/145/145813.png" alt=""></a>

    <a href="https://instagram.com/gev_abramyan?igshid=NTc4MTIwNjQ2YQ==" class="inst"><img class="instimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Instagram_icon.png/2048px-Instagram_icon.png" alt=""></a>

    <a href="https://t.me/GevAbramyan" class="tg"><img class="tgimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Telegram_2019_Logo.svg/800px-Telegram_2019_Logo.svg.png" alt=""></a>

    
  </div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
  <center>
    <a href="https://t.me/+pJZUq07C1wYzOTUy" class="eg"><b>разработчик сайта - E/G44</b></a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="inst44"><b>instagram erik_gevorgyan44</b></a>
  </center>

  <div class="btn-up btn-up_hide"></div>


<style>
  html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
  background-color: black;
}
.about{
  color: white;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -0.1vh;
}
.about-text{
  color: gold;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -5vh;
  
}



.aa{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gold;
}

.video-so-mnoy{
  color: white;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 35vh;
}

.contacts{
  color: white;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}
.number{
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -2vh;
  
}
.num{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.ss{
  text-align: center;
}
.vp{
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;

}
.mail{
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
}
.vkimg{
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 10vh;
  margin-top: 3vh;
}
.instimg{
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 10vh;
  margin-top: 3vh;
}
.tgimg{
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 20vh;
  margin-top: 3vh;


}

.eg{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: wheat;  
}


.inst44{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'TT Norms Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: wheat;
 

}




.btn-up {
  /* фиксированное позиционирование */
  position: fixed;
  /* цвет фона */
  background-color: wheat;
  /* расстояние от правого края окна браузера */
  right: 30px;
  /* расстояние от нижнего края окна браузера */
  bottom: 0;
  /* скругление верхнего левого угла */
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  /* скругление верхнего правого угла */
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  /* вид курсора */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* отображение элемента как flex */
  display: flex;
  /* выравниваем элементы внутри элемента по центру вдоль поперечной оси */
  align-items: center;
  /* выравниваем элементы внутри элемента по центру вдоль главной оси */
  justify-content: center;
  /* ширина элемента */
  width: 110px;
  /* высота элемента */
  height: 80px;
}

.btn-up::before {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M7.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 5.707l-5.646 5.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.btn-up_hide {
  display: none;
}

@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  .btn-up:hover {
    background-color: wheat; /* цвет заднего фона при наведении */
  }
}




</style>


  <script>
    const btnUp = {
  el: document.querySelector('.btn-up'),
  show() {
  
  this.el.classList.remove('btn-up_hide');
  },
  hide() {
  
  this.el.classList.add('btn-up_hide');
  },
  addEventListener() {
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrollY > 400 ? this.show() : this.hide();
  });
  document.querySelector('.btn-up').onclick = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
  }
  }
  
  btnUp.addEventListener();
  
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените свойства классов на следующие:

```
.slider {
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 1440px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider .previous, .slider .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

.slider .next {
  right: -5%;
}

.slider .previous{
  left: -5%;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое вы мне очень помогли